# Get Device details in React-native App

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I have to fetch device details like Unique Id, Device manufacturer, OS type and OS  version, user Locale from android and IOS devices/Simulators.
I have implemented by following this approach. I'm using React-native 0.49

In Project folder

```
npm install --save react-native-device-info
```

In JS file at imports section

```
var DeviceInfo= require('react-native-device-info');
```

then accessing by alert

```
alert(DeviceInfo.getUniqueID());
```

Its  throwing 'UNDEFINED IS NOT AN FUNCTION EVALUATING".

I have followed this **GITHUB** [LINK](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info)

Let me know where its going wrong.
Is there any other library to achieve this.

Comment: Did you use `react-native-cli` or `create-react-native-app` when starting project?

Comment: react-native-cli

Comment: Did you run `react-native link react-native-device-info`

Comment: i didnt link as i'm using React native 0.49

Comment: Last time I checked you still needed to link

Comment: You still have to link it either manually or with rnpm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i am using this same library for past 8 months.. this error maybe occurs some other function definitions. so please check your function definitions and then your approach is exactly correct there is no errors in DeviceInfo. But you should link      react-native link react-native-device-info before you use this library.

Comment: link react-native link react-native-device-info    actually helped me